# Can`t get to array variable PHP

Tags: php

I want to display only certain data from database on my page, so I end my `foreach` loop with `if` and `break;` statement. I checked with `var_dump()` and the data is being provided from database correctly, function `getName()` is also correct.

Moreover I inserted there a test `"echo"test";` which is displaying well. But `getName()` is still missing.

I think that problem might be with this `if` statement, because when I delete it everything works correctly (except that I get data I dont want to get).

Same situation is when I insert `if` statement after the `getName()` function - this part of the code is not executed, it seems.

```
<?php //var_dump($leagues); ?>
<?php foreach($leagues as $leauge): ?>
  <?php if($leauge->getLevel() != 'A') { break; } ?>
  <li>
    <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-right"></i>
    <?php $leauge->getName(); echo "test"; ?>
  </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There is one ***echo*** missing.

   Replace: `<?php $leauge->getName(); echo "test"; ?>`

   With: `<?php echo $leauge->getName(); ?>`
2. Consider to use ***continue;*** instead of ***break;***

> The break statement terminates the whole loop early whereas the
> continue brings the next iteration early. [Reference: Geeks for Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-break-and-continue-in-php)

As you are using ***break*** IF $leauge->getLevel() != 'A', in case of your first iteration goes to this condition, your entire loop will terminate. Just change to ***continue*** if you wanna "skip the current league, but go to the next one and check again".

Comment: No, sadly it didnt help at all.  The number of iteration of foreach loop is correct, and its not a problem. Problem is that the getName function doesnt give any output, though it should.

Comment: Moreover if i switch the lines of code places. And if first call the getName() function and will then check the end of loop condition. The loop will not end, even echo"test" not gonna show at all

Comment: @Gutek, can you try to use: <?php echo $leauge->getName(); ?> Please let me know. I think the "echo" is also missing, in addition to the break vs continue.

Comment: Sorry that i`m answering so late. Had a lof of things to do. In meanwhile i discovered what was bad. In this line of code '''<?php $leauge->getName(); echo "test"; ?>''' . When i want to display results i have to use '''<?=''' instead of '''<?php''' . Why is that i dont really know. But it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting it here so it will be more seeable. What helped me:
In this line of code

`<?php $leauge->getName(); echo "test"; ?>`

When i want to display results i have to use

`<?=` instead of `<?php` . Why is that i dont really know.

Comment: `<?=` is the shorthand equivalent of `<?php echo` as mentioned you should use in Leonardo Gomes' answer.

Comment: So actually you could also write `<?php echo $leauge->getName(); echo "test"; ?>` instead if you prefer.